# I want to change url in index

Tags: php

I want to change my url without creating another file:
my index.php file is not in a folder... and the other pages are in folder "about -> index.php", and so on... My footer for index page is like this:

```
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

and the footer from a folder like "about" is like this:

```
        <li><a href="../about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="../contact">Contact</a></li>
```

I want just 1 footer file not 2, is much faster to change data... 
Please help ! ( I prefer PHP )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use a leading slash `/` in your urls it will be base path. you're doing a relative path currently, which means you need to leave a directory then link to something.

like this:

```
example site url: www.mysite.com/about
<a href="/about">about</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put absolute reference to the link in footer e.g. www.mydomain.com/about

Comment: I know this, but I don't like it... any other options ?

Comment: Why dont you like this? You can use a global variable and set it to root of your site. So on local machine it will be something like http://localhost/mysite/ and then change it to http://www.mydomain.com when going live, so all absolute links will work with only one change

Comment: I know, but it's about domain... some people are using www.domain.com and the others are using domain.com... got it ?

Comment: Wont make a difference, the links on your site are the same for every user. Also, domain.com and www.domain.com is the same.

Comment: @Tommy Just wrong. They are two different domains and thats it. Wether they point to the same host depends on the DNS records. Beside: _Never_ recommend global variables again!